# Changing server for domain but what about email

Tags: email, dns, hosting

I have untypically problem. We are changing server for our app and to be able to do that we also need to change dns's of domain on new server.

The problem is that actually we have few email accounts. Is it possible to leave email accounts on oryginal server and just serve website from new server ?

I think that If i wanted to move also emails I guess I need to recreate them on new server but then I lost all emails. I know it depends from the hosting company but most of them share similar capabilities of "redirecting domains". How to solve this problem ?

Comment: What do you mean by you have email accounts? do you run an email server on your own in your server?

Comment: You can very well, host website and email on two separate servers for the same domain. If you add more details of your setup in your question I can help.

Comment: @mdeora thank you. Im not yet executing to solve the problem but I will post details when i Will have them. I read that i change A records of the domain on new server but im not really sure if i can leave adresses of the DNS. I guess DNS must be pointed to web server provider...

Answer (score 0):

> > The problem is that actually we have few email accounts. Is it possible to leave email accounts on oryginal server and just serve website from new server ?

This is possible, just need to point the MX dns record of the domain to point new server.

> > I think that If i wanted to move also emails I guess I need to recreate them on new server but then I lost all emails. I know it depends from the hosting company but most of them share similar capabilities of "redirecting domains". How to solve this problem ?

If you are looking for migrating the existing emails then if the new host provides the email client which supports the import of mail then its possible
to move all the existing emails also.